# Numerical methods for $u_t+c u_x= \frac{-c}{x}u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations, galerkin-methods

I am looking for possible numerical methods to solve the PDE
$$u_t+c u_x= \frac{-c}{x}u$$
for $u(x,t):\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and where $c>0$ is a constant.

I am particularly interested in a Finite elements method, although I am also curious if you can expose some other methods.

(I am refraining myself from writing the one or two methods that might be working to not influence the answers)

Comment: What do you know about $u$ for x near 0?

Comment: Without initial and/or boundary condition the solution is not determined and so cannot be found with numerical method. The analytical solution is $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}F(x-ct)$ with arbitrary function $F$.

Comment: Any form $u(x,t)= \frac{a}{x}F(x-ct)$ where $a$ is a constant is a solution, however I am looking for numerical methods for if we don't know necessarily this analytic solution.
@Paul I should include the initial condition $u(x,0)= f(x)$

Comment: With the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ the exact solution of the PDE is $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}(x-ct)f(x-ct)$$ Of course $f(x)$ must be known. So you can numerically compute $u(x,t)$ for given numerical values of $x$ and $t$. This is a method as you was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I am giving you alternative ideas to solve the PDE numerically.

Try using Fourier transform: let $\hat{u}(\omega,t)$ be the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$. So using the inverse Fourier transform, we can write $u$ as
$$ u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u(\omega, t)} e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i)} d \omega $$

and

$$ u_{t} =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}_{t}(\omega, t) e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i)} d \omega $$

$$ u_{x} =-(2 \pi \omega)^{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}(\omega, t) e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i) } d \omega $$

$$u_{t} + cu_{x} =   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}_{t}(\omega, t) e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i)} d \omega  -c(2 \pi \omega)^{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}(\omega, t) e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i) } d \omega  $$

$$  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[ \hat{u}_{t}(\omega, t) -c(2 \pi \omega)^{2} \hat{u}(\omega,t) ] e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i) } d \omega  $$

but your right hand side has $1/x$ which is a problem. If it does not have, assume it is just $c u(x,t)$, then we have

$$ -c u(x,t) = -c \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{u}(\omega,t)  e^{2 \pi  \omega x (i) } d \omega $$

So your PDE is equivalent with the below ODE (in frequency domain):

$$ \hat{u}_{t}(\omega, t) -c(2 \pi \omega)^{2} \hat{u}(\omega,t)  = -c \hat{u}(\omega,t) $$

You can then solve this either numerically using finite difference, or solving it analytically. But to deal with your right hand side that includes $1/x$, you may need to do some adjustment.

Comment: this answer might be applicable, but it does not seem to address the questions being asked.

Comment: @Doug I edit the answer. It gives alternative ideas, since not few that don't know this method.